# Fantasy novel featuring a war, two distinct sides, and possibly the colour green/jade?

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

This was a book I read when I was about 13, around the year 2002. I borrowed it from the school library at the time and really enjoyed the story (at least, I think I remember enjoying it). I've marked it as YA, but I don't know if it actually was. Anyway, I've completely forgotten what it's called, and it's honestly bugged me for probably the best part of 8-10 years.

As I remember it, the story centred around a war/conflict point between two fantasy nations. Both races were humanoid, with the first being potentially elf-like (knights, armour, swords, beautiful hair(?!)) whereas the second were more... savage? Not so much armour, less swords, and wielding weapons I distinctly recall being described as something like crude black powder weaponry. I wouldn't go so far as to call them guns as we have known them throughout our own history, more like... clubs that exploded projectiles.

That's about all the plot points I can really remember. But I do seem to recall that the savage race were invading the other, and that they potentially were from across the sea.

As for any further detail? Green, Jade, Moon are keywords I seems to recall from the title.

It is not *The Green and The Gray* by Timothy Zahn.

Comment: This probably isn't it, but a fight between two fantasy peoples, one "Green"... [link=https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/216455.The_Green_and_the_Gray?from_search=true&search_version=service]Zelazny's The Green and The Gray[/link]?

Can you remember anything else?  Does this fight take place on Earth, or on Fantasy World?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not it unfortunately, I'm sure this book would have been published much earlier. I believe it was a fantasy world as well.

Comment: Augh, I'm sorry.  I didn't even realize The Green and the Gray was published in 2005.  It felt like an older book when I read it.

Comment: While it postdates your 2002 timeframe, a possibility is the alternate Napoleonic war history [*Temeraire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temeraire_(series)) series. (Note the cover/title of the second book, Throne of Jade)

Comment: @JohnP Appreciate the comment! I came across that book several times during my scouring of the internet. I definitely know it can't be that as I do remember reading the book during a specific year at school. Thanks though!